# Mongodb schema diff

Tags: mongodb

**Is there any open source tool available for diffing two different mongodb schemas?** 
E.g. 
If Schema M1 has collections C1, C2, C3, C4
Schema M2 has collections C1, C2, C3. Are any open source tools available to get the diff between them? Also want to compare the indexes in both the schemas M1 and M2.

I would imagine it would be possible to do basic stuff using a script or a simple java program using the java mongodb driver. Just looking to see if anyone already has come across such a tool? I am thinking along the lines of liquibase for relational schemas.

I came across Mongeez from Second Market with some initial search. Does anyone have experience using it?

Comment: [Mongeez](http://engineering.secondmarket.com/post/17156303982/mongo-mongeez) looks like a close fit (at least for managing changesets). They even mention relying on Liquibase for relational models and appear to be using a similar XML schema approach in Mongeez ;-).  Why don't you try it and see how it works?

Comment: Thanks @Stennie. i wrote a diff script myself. the task I was trying to achieve was too simple. Plus we are using a PHP setup, so Mongeez would not help out-of-the-box.